# How to use concat with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to update a table field with a new value provided like

if the field current value is 100 once updated with value 200, it should be 100,200

so i tried

```
$this->db->set('return', 'CONCAT(return,',','.$loan_number.')', FALSE); 
$this->db->where( 'id', $this->input->post('id') );
$this->db->update('tbl_test');
```

i think im using CONCAT in wrong way though.

any idea how to get this work?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with you quotes. This code gives four parameters to `$this->db->set()`: `return`, `CONCAT(return,`, `,'{loan_number}` and `FALSE`. Your trying to append `,{loan_number}` to return right? If so then you should either escape you quotes ore use different quotes.

Escaping:

```
$this->db->set('return', 'CONCAT(return,\',\',\''.$loan_number.'\')', FALSE);
```

Different qutes:

```
$this->db->set('return', "CONCAT(return,',','".$loan_number."')", FALSE);
```

Comment: Tip: I always use DOUBLE QUOTES around my SQL so i can safely use SINGLE QUOTES inside a query ;)

Comment: And also basic debugging: After query echo `$this->db->last_query()` and if you can't see from there what's wrong, then copy it to phpMyAdmin and run/edit/debug in there, until you get code right.

Comment: yeah thanks a lot still getting syntax error, but if i use backticks (`) to cover return table name inside set() it works

Comment: Alsi put quotes around `$loan_number`, using escaping: `\''.$loan_number.'\'` and same style `'".$loan_number."'` otherwise loan number is taken as column name not string value